# Why kivy changes all widgets at once

Tags: python, kivy

I create a subclass of the Button widget. While handling on_touch_down event I want to change button text for debugging purpose. When I click a single button, all the buttons of this type got their text changed. Why? How to change text on a clicked button only?

Button class:

```
class FigureButton(Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        super(FigureButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)
        self.text = 'Clicked'
```

.kv file portion:

```
FigureButton:
    text: '1'
FigureButton:
    text: '2'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Had to bind a callback to on_press event for the button. Callback received an instance which is used to change it's text. Any comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`on_touch_down` doesn't do collision checking, so that widgets can interact with touches outside their area. You can add '`if self.collide_point(*touch.pos): ...` before your code (and indent your additions into the if statement) to have this work as you expect.

As you have discovered, the `on_press` event/method does do collision checking. This is normally a better way to interact with buttons anyway.