# How can I access different widget classes in Kivy that are not part of root?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to add a screen to a screen manager but that screen is separate. Meaning it is not part of the root element just a class sitting off by itself. I want to add this screen to the screen manager when an icon is pressed but i cannot figure out how to reference the screen in my kv file.

And i guess in general how do you reference widgets in the kv lang that are not part of the root widget (are of a separate class)?

usb_screen_manager.kv

```
#:import label kivy.uix.label
#:import sla kivy.adapters.simplelistadapter
#:import hvt hub_validation_test


<UsbScreenManager>:
    id: manager
    H2HScreen:
    HubValidationScreen:


<H2HScreen>:
    id: h2h
    name: 'h2h'
    BoxLayout:
        id:bl
        orientation: 'vertical'
        TestIcon:
            id: h2hicon
            source: 'h2h.png'


<HubValidationScreen>:
    id: hvs
    name: 'hvs'
    BoxLayout:
        id:bl
        orientation: 'vertical'

        TestIcon:
            id: hubvicon
            source: 'usb_button.png'
            on_touch_down: app.root.manager.switch_to(hvts) <--add screen when this icon is pressed
        Label:
            text: 'Hub Validation test' 
            size_hint: (1,.25)


<HubValidationTestScreen>:
    id: hvts
    name: 'hvts'
    BoxLayout:
        ListView:
            adapter:
                sla.SimpleListAdapter(
                data= hvt.requirements,
                cls= label.Label)
```

sam1.kv (kv file containing root element)

```
<MainPanel>:
    id: mp
    manager: manager

    size_hint: 1,1
    tab_width: 65
    do_default_tab: False
    tab_pos: 'top_right'


    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: usb_tab
        text: 'Usb'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            UsbScreenManager:
                id: manager
            NavLayout:
                id: nav

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: remote_tab
        text: 'Remote'

    TabbedPanelItem:
        id: sd_tab
        text: 'SD'





<NavLayout>:
    id: nav
    spacing: 5,5
    rows: 1
    size_hint: 1, .2


    LeftButton:
        id: left_arrow_button
        on_release: app.root.manager.current = app.root.manager.previous()
        Image:
            source: 'left_arrow_iconb.png'
            center: left_arrow_button.center
            size: nav.width*.8, nav.height*.8

    BackButton:
        id: back_button

        Image:
            source: 'back_iconb.png'
            center: back_button.center
            size: nav.width*.8, nav.height*.8
    RightButton:
        id: right_arrow_button
        on_release: app.root.manager.current = app.root.manager.next()
        Image:
            source: 'right_arrow_iconb.png'
            center: right_arrow_button.center
            size: nav.width*.8, nav.height*.8
```

Comment: I partly figured this out by using the Kivy Properties. In my py file i added a  variable with an ObjectPropert(ClassName) then used that property variable in my kv file. Only problem use when i tried to the same thing to add a Screen to the ScreenManager using the switch_to method it states "Screen Manager can only accept Screens". So even though the variable I set is a screen the ScreenManager method does not see it as so.

Comment: Why not do it in the python code? Create an instance of your screen (the layout can be defined in the KV file) and then add that instance to the screen manager.

Comment: I am trying to get it done in kv. Also I am attempting to use the on_touch_down method of that specific TestIcon instance since I will be using the TestIcon class in many places in my app. If i define in python, that method will fire across all instances and i do not know how to set that method in python so it only uses that TestIcon instance.

Comment: On the `on_touch_down` point, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089990/why-kivy-changes-all-widgets-at-once).

Comment: You could also get your `TestIcon` class to subclass the [`ButtonBehaviour`](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.behaviors.html) and then use the `on_press` event.

Comment: I still run into the same issue of that event being fired across all instances. Thank you for the link but it still does not show how to get a certain instance or at least check against one. I tried self.ids (if self.ids.hubvicon:)  route to grab the specific instance but did not work. Got "super object has no attribute 'getattr'.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a "better" way of doing this but here we go.

First of all I have to state that Kivy Properties, in this instance ObjectProperty(), may not be as they seem. As the docs state an ObjectProperty may *represent* a python object but let it be known it will not be the actual object. This matters when that ObjectProperty has to pass the isinstance test because it will fail.

I mention this because I thought I had solved my problem when I had to reference my ListViewLabel class from another class in Kivy. (I created a ListViewLabel class to properly format a list I will be displaying in the screen). I did this using ObjectProperty and it worked like a charm.

```
in main.py
class HubValidationTestScreen(Screen):
    lvl = ObjectProperty(ListViewLabel)
    #manager = ObjectProperty(UsbScreenManager)
    pass

in kv file

<HubValidationTestScreen>:
    id: hvts
    name: 'hvts'
    BoxLayout:
        ListView:
            adapter:
                sla.SimpleListAdapter(
                data= hvt.requirements,
                cls= root.lvl) <---I'm a genius! (not really)
```

So when I tried the same thing trying to switch the screen I instead received an error stating 'ScreenManager only accepts Screens'. Umm ya, thats what i was trying to do. Problem was that in http://kivy.org/docs/_modules/kivy/uix/screenmanager.html when adding a screen it has to pass the isinstance test

```
 if not isinstance(screen, Screen):
            raise ScreenManagerException(
                'ScreenManager accepts only Screen widget.')
```

and it was failing.

So I found out how to reference another class but it was not working for this.
I wanted all my classes to be separate, including the screens, so I just call them when I need them. So to be able to switch to the screen what I did was added the screen under my ScreenManager like the other two and during the initialization of the screenmanager I removed the screen hoping the id still stayed with screen manager. And it did. So when the button is pressed I give the illusion of a new screen by adding the one and removing the other two. I am then going to implement a 'back' button which reverses this action.

```
<UsbScreenManager>:
    id: manager
    hvts:hvts
    h2h: h2h
    H2HScreen:
        id:h2h
    HubValidationScreen:
        id:hvs
    HubValidationTestScreen:
        id: hvts

class UsbScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    hvts = ObjectProperty()
    h2h = ObjectProperty()
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        Clock.schedule_once(self.remove, .5)

        print(str(self.ids))
        super(UsbScreenManager, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def remove(self, b):
        self.remove_widget(self.hvts)
    pass

<HubValidationScreen>:
    id: hvs
    name: 'hvs'


    BoxLayout:
        id:bl
        orientation: 'vertical'

        TestIcon:
            id: hubvicon

            source: 'usb_button.png'
            on_press: hvs.manager.switch_to(app.root.manager.hvts); app.root.manager.remove_widget(app.root.manager.h2h)
```

Comment: When I use ScreenManager I tend to do the adding/removing of screens in the python code. That way I can create a Screen instance, assign it to a variable and then just do `remove_widget(name_of_variable)`. However, if you've got a solution that works, then well done!